# Error with creating new folder

Tags: android, createfile

Hello right now Im trying to download some files on my server to my phone with my app. I'm trying to write it on my storage but not on my sdcard!

I have the necessary permissions on my device in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is my code from the DownloaderClass to create new folder. I get the return Download complete... and in the debugger it is showing me the path it is saving it in exactly where I want it, but if I look there .... the folder the Folder should be in is empty.

```
        //File new_Folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "MY DOWNLOADED FILES");
        String intStorageDirectory = context.getFilesDir().toString();
        File new_Folder = new File(intStorageDirectory, "MY DOWNLOADED FILES");
        if (!new_Folder.exists()) {
            if (!new_Folder.mkdir()) {
                return "ERROR: mkdirs() failed for directory" + new_Folder.getAbsolutePath();
            }

        } else {
            Log.i("Info:", "Folder already exists");
        }

        /**
         * Create an output file to store the file for download
         */

        inputoutput_file = new File(new_Folder, "downloaded_files.jpg");


        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
        //this will read the information in 1 KB
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int total = 0;
        int count;

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(inputoutput_file);

        while ((count = inputStream.read(data))!= -1){
            total+=count;

            if (file_length>0) {
                int progress = total * 100 / file_length;
                publishProgress(progress);
                outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
                Log.i("Info:", "Progress: " + Integer.toString(progress));
            }
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

        return "Download Complete...";

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "ERROR MalformedURLException" + e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "ERROR IOException" + e.getMessage();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** just change your folder path to

```
"/sdcard/insertyourpreferredfoldername/"
```

and it creates the folder internal. Adjust the

```
downloaded_file.jpg
```

variable to your filename you get from the server and it will save the files seperately!

EDIT: Thanks to greenapps
 for leading me the right way!

Comment: @greenapps Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Go on your device to the Settings for your app and switch the Permission toggle for Storage to On.

Comment: Can I do that programmaticly somehow? and it does still not work even with the permission toggelt

Comment: Are you telling that stil mkdirs() is unable to create that directory?

Comment: exactly there doenst happen anything eve tho the path that is shown in the debugger is given to a folder that doesnt exist.

Comment: Yes mkdirs() fails.  But if you put the Storage toggle on On then it should work. And you do not have to search for that folder if you see a Toast with the mkdirs() failed error.

Comment: I dont I just see the download complete... toast I get no Error

Comment: Well then the file is saved in internal private memory. And you cannot find it with a File Explorer app. That is normal. I explained that already.